# Where to create an AF_LOCAL/AF_UNIX socket file when not allowed to write in /var/run?

Tags: filesystems, socket, pid

FSH says that socket and pid files should go to `/var/run`
However, for security purpose, only root can creates file and subdirectories in this location.

A common solution is creating a subdirectory for the script in `/var/run` and ten chmod it... But what to do when you don't have access to root user ?

Where should I put a .socket (and a .pid) if I don't have access to root ?

Comment: On what Linux distribution?

Comment: Archlinux and Debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On systemd-based systems such as Arch Linux and (latest) Debian, services are expected to tell systemd that they want a directory under `/run` by adding a a `tmpfiles.d` configuration file to the system.

By default these are stored in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d`, though local additions can be added in `/etc/tmpfiles.d` which override the defaults.

The [tmpfiles.d facility](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html) can be used to create and empty directories, create files, symlinks, device nodes, sockets, and more.

For example:

```
# cat /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/php-fpm.conf
d /run/php-fpm 755 root root
```

This specifies to create a directory `/run/php-fpm`, with mode 0755, owned by root and group root. The directory will be created at system startup or whenever the [`systemd-tmpfiles-setup` service](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html) is restarted. You can also run `systemd-tmpfiles` manually.

There are many other options available; check the [tmpfiles.d documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html) for full details.

Comment: is there a similar way with system v ? (cause I've also a VPS on old debian)

Comment: Upgrade to jessie? There was no "standard" way of handling this prior to systemd creating one.